# Next js with Prisma: Upsert based on two conditions

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to do the following using Prisma:

If a category row with the same hash and user_id I have exists, just update it's "name" field, otherwise, create the row

Is this possible? TS is giving me an error saying that the type of the key given on "where" has to be of `categoriesWhereUniqueInput`, yet neither hash nor user_id are unique, they can repeat, it's the combination between the two that's gonna be unique

How can I work around this? Do I have to manually check if there's an id and update/create based on that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```js
  const category = await prisma.categories.upsert({
    where: {
      hash,
      user_id: id,
    },
    update: {
      name,
    },
    create: {
      hash,
      name,
      user_id: id,
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a combination of fields is unique, Prisma will generate a new type for the `where` condition which is basically just the name of all the relevant fields appended together with `_`.

Take a look at the `categoriesWhereUniqueInput` to see what the name is. Most likely it is called `user_id_hash` or `hash_user_id`.

This is what the query will look like, roughly speaking:

```js
const category = await prisma.categories.upsert({
    where: {
        user_id_hash: {  // user_id_hash is the type generated by Prisma. Might be called something else though. 
            user_id: 1,
            hash: "foo"
        }
    },
    update: {
        name: "bar",
    },
    create: {
        hash: "foo",
        name: "bar",
        user_id: 1,
    },
})
```

Comment: Is there an updated answer? This does not seem to work with prisma v3.

Comment: Hey @j_d could you share your schema and the query you want to achieve? It should still work to the best of my knowledge. (perhaps create a new question and link it here)

Comment: I have a table of bank accounts. I want to upsert a bank account by ID, where update only occurs if the ID matches, and also the userId field matches, otherwise create new.

The answer given above does not work.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is wrong without looking at the schema. Could you please create a post on stackoverflow or [prisma discussions](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions) with the schema and the query you have tried? @j_d

Comment: I haven't "tried" any schema, as literally everything except a single unique column query fails as per the TypeScript types. Feel free to give a dummy example if you are aware of something I'm not.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this: if you cannot find the option in the `where` clause to select by `user_id_hash`, then you need to first have declared the unique composite constraint in the table definition.

```
 @@unique([fieldOne, fieldTwo])
```

After doing this you will be able to select in code, on the `where` condition: `fieldOne_fieldTwo`.